# How to get the 'id' of PATCH request in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The PATCH request looks something like this `"PATCH /api/details/43/ HTTP/1.1"`. I want to get the `id` from that request viz. `43`. I am using `ModelViewSet` and overriding `initalize_request`.

I tried to `MyModel.objects.get()` inside `initalize_request` but its returning more than one objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the signature of `initialize_request` is like below:

```
def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The ID (primary key) is in `kwargs`:

```
pk = kwargs.get("pk")
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to override `initalize_request`. That's why I can't use `pk`